# Make code more efficient displaying multiple images with EXIF metadata in caption box on site page

Tags: javascript, html, exif-js

I’m creating a site page that will display images/photo in a row.  Underneath the images I’m displaying a caption box that displays the image/photo EXIF metadata for “Image Description”.  I have it displaying properly on the page but each time I add a new image (new to update); I have to write in the new image in my html and JavaScript.  I have to type in the call to extract the EXIF metadate for the new image placed in the source folder.  Is there a way I can optimize my code to dynamically add the image to the DOM from the source folder and also extract/add the EXIF data from the new image and place it in the caption box?
I figured out how dynamically add the images form the folder into DOM, but I can’t figure out how to extract the EXIF metadata with this method.  I’m stuck with the original solution of hard coding in everything when a new image/photo is added to the source folder, but this is not too efficient.  To extract the EXIF metadata, I’m using exif.js; which works great extracting the metadata.
Here's the working hard coding script:

```
<div id="parent" > </div>    
  
    <script>
    var folder = "images/";

    $.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
             
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
                $("#parent").append( "<div class='alignImage'><img src="+ folder + val +" id='image"+i+"'><div class=' makeAndModel'>Description: <span id='makeAndModel"+i+"''> Placholder content. </span></div></div>" );
                
            var image = document.getElementById("image"+i);
                EXIF.getData(image, function() {
                var desc = EXIF.getTag(this, "ImageDescription");
                var makeAndModel = document.getElementById("makeAndModel"+i);
                    
                makeAndModel5.innerHTML = `${desc}`;    
                document.getElementById("makeAndModel"+i).innerHTML = `${desc}`;
                    
               });
                
            } 
        });
    }
});

    </script>
```

Comment: What is `EXIF` referring to? Is it a JavaScript library?

Comment: Yes, EXIF is the metadata stored on a photo and I'm using the EXIF.js JavaScript library to extract the metadata and placing it into a div.  Here's a link to EXIF.js.  https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js#exifjs

Comment: Update to my progress.  I was able to extract the EXIF from the dynamic loading image in side the folder.  New issue, I have to reload the browser for the metadata to load in the caption DIV.  I looked up solution for this issue but could find one that works.  Any suggestion how this issue can be solved.  I updated my code with my new code.

Comment: One other issue.  My id count begins a 5 and not 1.  I can't figure our while that is.